# How do $\arctan(f(x))$ and $\ln(g(x))$ relate?

Tags: calculus, functions, logarithms

I've seen these two functions often appear interchangeably in differential equation and integral solutions. There seems to be an intuitive relation between those two.

One can also notice their similarity on the basic composite function integrals:

$$\int \frac{f(x)f'(x)}{f(x)^2+1} dx = \frac12 \ln\left|f^2(x)+1\right| +C \quad (1)$$
$$\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2+1} dx = \arctan\left|f(x)\right| +C\quad (2)$$

---

**My question is:**

Is there a way to write $\arctan(f(x)) = \ln(g(x))$, with the restriction that $f,g$ are real functions?.

In other words, is there a way to reduce $\arctan$ functions to $\ln$'s and visa-versa?

Comment: One most important condition is also that $\text{im}(g) = \mathbb{R}^{+}$

Comment: @RalphClausen $f,g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$. So by the definition of the problem yeah

Comment: @RalphClausen How is the Taylor expansion of arctan related to ln?

Comment: I don't believe your second integral.

Comment: @user10354138 And you are right. I corrected it. $f(x)$ shouldn't be squared in arctan

Comment: @Veriun I mistakenly did it. Sorry! :(

Comment: @RalphClausen hahah no worries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why they often appear next to each other is

$$\int\frac{dz}z=\log(z)=\log(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})+i\arctan\left(\frac yx\right).$$

This integral is at the very heart of the calculus of residues and is ubiquitous in the antiderivative of rational functions.