# Weird looking ODE solution: How to verify this is indeed a solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question

I will try to express my question using an example.

Consider this homogeneous ODE: $y' = \frac{y-x}{x+y }$

Its solution is: $\boxed{\frac12 \log\left( \frac{y^2(x)}{x^2} +1\right) - \log(x) + \arctan\left( \frac{y(x)}{x}\right) = c} \quad  c\in \mathbb{R}$

---

As far as I am understanding solving a differential equation means finding a $y(x)$ that satisfies the differential equation.

But this particular solution, cannot be expressed in terms of $y(x)$ **(at least I can't)**.

- If the previous argument is true how could one verify the solution, given the fact that there is no actual $y$ to plug into the ODE?
- If the previous argument is false, how could the solution be expressed in terms of $y$?

P.S: A previous question I've asked is [How do $\arctan$ and $\ln$ relate?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768533/how-do-arctanfx-and-lngx-relate-on-mathbbr-plane). Given the fact that the solution only contains those two functions, I suspect that it may be helpful to note this down. Could there be some complex analysis involved?

Comment: Differentiate and plug in the DE and see if it works

Comment: How can you express $ y(x) $ with respect to $ y(x) $ itself.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Differentiate as Aryadeva proposed. Thanks!

Comment: Yes Dimitri implicit differentiation of the solution will do the job....The solution can be simplified since you have $\dfrac 12 \log x^2 $ twice with opposite sign.

Comment: As to how that is "solving the ODE", seen from a numerical perspective, this implicit form is an improvement over the raw IVP in that the constant can be determined from the initial point, and for every fixed $x$ one has a smooth equation for $y(x)$ that has a unique solution if one restricts the search domain to a single branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y' = \frac{y-x}{x+y }$$
$$(x+y)dy+(x-y)dx=0$$
$$xdy-ydx+\dfrac 12d(x^2+y^2)=0$$
$$\dfrac {xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2} +\dfrac 12\dfrac {d(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}=0$$
Integration gives:
$$2\arctan (y/x)+ \ln (x^2+y^2)=C$$
You can also differentiate the solution. I mean implicit differentiation. And you can also simplify the $\log$ function in the  given solution. It should simply be $\dfrac 12 \log (x^2+y^2)$.

Comment: Great answer, as always @Aryadeva. I'm out of votes, but I'll upvote tommorow. Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you. You're welcome. @Dimitris

Answer (score 1):

Use the substitution $y = xv$

$$v+xv' = \frac{x(v-1)}{x(v+1)} \implies xv' = -\frac{v^2+1}{v+1}$$

which is separable

$$\int\frac{v}{v^2+1} + \frac{1}{v^2+1} \:dv = -\int\frac{dx}{x} \implies \frac{1}{2}\log\left(v^2+1\right)+ \tan^{-1}v = -\log|x| + C$$

which means the solution can be given as

$$\frac{1}{2}\log\left(x^2v^2+x^2\right) + \tan^{-1}v = C \implies \log(y^2+x^2) + 2 \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) = C$$